# field automorphism action on $Ext^1(\mathbb{C}^*,\mathbb{Z})$ or $Ext^1(\bar{\mathbb Q}^\star,\mathbb{Z})$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, absolute-galois-group

I am interested in the action of field automorphism group $Aut(\mathbb{C}/\mathbb{Q})$ on 
$Ext^1(\mathbb{C}^{\star},\mathbb{Z})$ or $Ext^1(\mathbb{\bar Q}^*,\mathbb{Z})$, and, more generally, on
$Ext^1_{EndA}(A(\mathbb{C}),\pi_1(A(\mathbb{C},0))/Aut_{EndA}(\pi_1(A(\mathbb{C},0) )$ for $A$ 
a commutative algebraic group.  I am wondering whether this kind of questions have been considered
in algebraic geometry, e.g. in relation to the full *algebraic* fundamental group of 
A(C) or $A(\mathbb{\bar Q})$ as a scheme over $\mathbb Q$.

These have been studied in logic (see http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0511591, http://arxiv.org/abs/0704.3561 , 
and also [this](http://people.maths.ox.ac.uk/bays/dist/thesis/thesis.pdf) ),   and 
are related to questions of arithmetics, such as Galois action on a Tate module.

The main result of these papers is the following; from the point of view of logic it is a *categoricity* theorem. First note that $ exp :\mathbb{C}\rightarrow \mathbb{C}^\star$ gives an element of $Ext^1(\mathbb{C}^{\star},\mathbb{Z})$ (and also $Ext^1(\mathbb{\bar Q}^*,\mathbb{Z})$). Then the orbit of this extensions consists of all extensions where the middle is an $\mathbb{Q}$-vector space. A similar result is known about the covers of elliptic curves in char 0. 
Also, I may mention that there are partial analogues  in prime characteristic.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "algebraic" fundamental group? The etale fundamental group? Or the Schur multiplier (second homology with integer coefficients)?

Comment: the etale fundamental group $\pi_1^{et}(A\tensor C,0)$ where $A$ is my algebraic group.